# how to validate if one number is greater than other inside form rule?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

Form contains two items, both of it is an input field that accepts a number. I need to check if the value entered in the first input (start) is always less than the second (end) or else, show a validation error.

[image: UI]

The above is wrapper inside antd form and each of it is a `Form.Item`.
I need show validation message like this,

[image: Validation error expected]

Code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(1);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(2);
  const formRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (end < start) {
      console.log("End cannot be lesser than start");
    } else if (end === start) {
      console.log("End cannot be same as start");
    } else {
      console.log("Added :)", start, end);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form
      onFinish={handleSubmit}
      layout="vertical"
      ref={formRef}
      requiredMark={false}
    >
      <div>
        <Form.Item
          name="formStart"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please select a form start"
            }
          ]}
        >
          <InputNumber
            placeholder="Start"
            min={1}
            max={100}
            onChange={(e) => setStart(e)}
          />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name="formEnd"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please select a form end"
            }
          ]}
        >
          <InputNumber
            placeholder="End"
            min={1}
            max={100}
            onChange={(e) => setEnd(e)}
          />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <button htmlType="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

If there is an alternative instead of using setState, It can also use ref (formRef.current)

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-21-0-forked-4sri66?file=/demo.js

Comment: Do you want to trigger the validation when typing in End input field, not after submit? Am I correct?

Comment: I need them after submitting. That too works

Comment: I put an answer and sample demo without use of useRef or internal state. check if it is the way you looked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **custom validations or conditional validations** we need to include `'validator'` inside our `rules` as below as per the `antd` docs.

```
<Form.Item
      name="formEnd"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Please select a form end"
        },
        ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
          validator(rule, value) {
            // from 'getFieldValue("fieldName")' we can get the current value of that field.
            if (value < getFieldValue("formStart")) {
              // value = currentValue of this field. with that we can do validations with other values in form fields
              return Promise.reject("End range must be greater than start"); // The validator should always return a promise on both success and error
            } else if (value === getFieldValue("formStart")) {
              return Promise.reject("End cannot be same as start");
            } else {
              return Promise.resolve();
            }
          }
        })
      ]}
    >
```

With this approach, you can achieve above validation without use of internal state and also without `useRef`.

**Few points for when use antd form**

1. antd form has `Form.useForm` which create Form instance to maintain data store. With this we can easily get the current form state like values, errors etc.
2. It also has `form.submit()` function which trigger the given function for Form `onFinish`. So we can use that for SUBMIT Btn onClick.

Here is the full [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-form-custom-validation-72599933-uln7ko?file=/demo.js) code in codesandbox.

Check this [form/API](https://ant.design/components/form/#API) for more `antd Form` props and functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef`:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
```

Define ref variables:

```js
const start = useRef();
const end = useRef();
```

Pass the refs to the inputs:

```js
<InputNumber placeholder="Start" min={1} max={100} ref={start} />
<InputNumber placeholder="End" min={1} max={100} ref={end} />
```

Access the input values:

```js
if (end.current.value < start.current.value) {
    // some code
}
```

You can also set the default values by adding the `defaultValue` attribute. For example:

```js
<InputNumber placeholder="Start" min={1} max={100} ref={start} defaultValue={1} />
```

Comment: Yeah, but how will i set the if statement in a form rule ?

Comment: The if statement is an example of how you can access the value of that input. In the `handleSubmit` function, you should replace the `end` with `end.current.value` and the `start` with `start.current.value`.

Comment: That isn't my question. The if statement in my code is fine. 
I need to show validation error if end is less than start. 
You can see a rule in form.item which shows error if the value isn't entered while submitting. Similary I need to show error if the end is less than start

Comment: I think you can add custom validation by adding a `validator` key and pass it a function. You can check their documentation for more information.

Comment: I guess validator are used to customize